# How to sync a patched file version to master?

Tags: git, rebase

I have a git patch that applies to a past version of a file:

```
A - B - C - D - G - Master
     \       
      patch1
```

I apply my patch by running

```
git checkout B
git apply patch1
```

Now I want to update my file to the latest version in master, seems to me that there might be a few options:

- patch + rebase
- patch the latest version directly
- "rebase" the patch itself and then apply it to master, but I don't know if that is even possible

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to carry a patch is

```
git checkout -t -b mystuff origin/master 
git config branch.mystuff.rebase true

git apply patch1
git commit -am 'my stuff'
```

and then when you're on `mystuff` and you want to update

```
git pull
```